# Angular 17 prerender doesn't work after update

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

Angular 16 uses `@nguniversal/builders:prerender` as a builder for Prerender which works fine, After upgrading to Angular 17 ng update changes this builder to `@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender` and after running `ng run <project-name>:prerender` there's a warning which says `An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'production' is not set in the workspace.` I can't fix this error but it continues running after this error and writes `✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.` `✔ Copying assets complete.` `✔ Index html generation complete.` but there's no prerendered page generated. here is my angular.json file:

```
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "karlancer": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {},
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                      "outputPath": "dist/karlancer",
                      "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
                        "rxjs-compat",
                        "rxjs",
                        "hammerjs"
                      ],
                      "index": "src/index.html",
                      "main": "src/main.ts",
                      "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                      "aot": true,
                      "assets": [
                        "src/assets",
                        "src/robots.txt"
                      ],
                      "styles": [
                        "src/styles.css",
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                      ],
                      "scripts": [
                        "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
                        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                      ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [{
                                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                            }],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "budgets": [{
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                                    "maximumError": "6mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                                    "maximumError": "20kb"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "buildOptimizer": false,
                            "optimization": false,
                            "vendorChunk": true,
                            "extractLicenses": false,
                            "sourceMap": true,
                            "namedChunks": true
                          }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                      "buildTarget": "karlancer:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                          "buildTarget": "karlancer:build:production"
                        },
                        "development": {
                          "buildTarget": "karlancer:build:development"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                      "buildTarget": "karlancer:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/assets",
                            "src/robots.txt"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "src/styles.css"
                        ],
                        "scripts": []
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "karlancer:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "karlancer:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "server": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/karlancer/server",
                        "main": "server.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
                        "optimization": false,
                        "buildOptimizer": false
                    }
                },
                "serve-ssr": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ssr-dev-server",
                    "options": {
                      "browserTarget": "karlancer:build",
                      "serverTarget": "karlancer:server"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                      "production": {
                        "browserTarget": "karlancer:build:production",
                        "serverTarget": "karlancer:server:production"
                      }
                    }
                },
                "prerender": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "karlancer:build:production",
                        "serverTarget": "karlancer:server:production",
                        "routes": [
                            "/"
                          ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "karlancer:build:production",
                            "serverTarget": "karlancer:server:production"
                        }
                    },
                    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "cli": {
        "analytics": false
    }
}
```

Which I found out the builder has changed from angular 17 as said in [Angular documents](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild)

it can be updated with `ng update @angular/cli --name use-application-builder` command which changes the builder to application in that case the prerender is an option which is used in this builder. When you set that option to true or declare routes in it after building this error code appears `Error: NG0908` it has been told in other resources this is due to `polyfills.js` being loaded after `main.js` but these loading sequences are out of my control.
I need to run prerender on Angular 17 but I can't find an example on github or anything that works.

Comment: did you found solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error with prerender after upgrading a project to angular 17. I checked out this working example on github where prerendering works with Angular 17 and the application builder: https://github.com/ganatan/angular-ssr

The actual cause of the `Error: NG0908` is when you specify the `src/polyfills.ts` file in the `Angular.json` "polyfills" option. In the example, `'zone.js'` is directly declared in the "polyfills" options in the Angular.json.

To solve the problem, in your Angular.json file, change from:

```
"polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts"
```

to this:

```
"polyfills": ["zone.js"]
```

I also removed the `src/polyfills.ts` from the `tsconfig.app.json` "files" list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to run prerender in Angular 17. When I execute the prerender command, I receive the following error message: "window is not defined".

Here's the relevant section of the error message:

```
Error: window is not defined
```

I've tried various solutions found online, such as ensuring that the code using window is placed within a conditional block checking for its existence, but the error persists.

Here's the relevant portion of my Angular configuration (angular.json):

```
{
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {
      "architect": {
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:prerender",
          "options": {
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what's causing this issue or how to resolve it. Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35838047)